# Starting point for Java client/server remote application

Tags: java, networking, client

I have an existing java project that I wish to create a mobile 'remote control' application that is capable of calling a few public methods from the existing project.

I have no previous experience of any sort of networking development so would appreciate some guidance on where I should start. I've found a few libraries out there but I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking for (or if I'm overcomplicating things!).

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: and how do you want to expose your server side code? using restful? soap? rmi? plain sockets? do you have any restrictions?

Comment: Can you describe your "existing java project" a bit more? What kind of application is it? A desktop application? A server application? What kind of software stack are you using?

Comment: I'm basically trying to write a remote keyboard app, where I can use the keyboard on my android phone to type on to my computer (I'm aware these things already exist, I'm just trying to get to grips with the programming!).

I've already written an 'on screen keyboard' java application and I'm basically looking for a way to control this via my android phone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java RMI technology may be what you need, here's where to start http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html. It can be used when both client and server are in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use webservices you could take a look at this [Exposing existing API as a Web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846783/exposing-existing-api-as-a-web-service)

You could check this out [Java client/server application with sockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776457/java-client-server-application-with-sockets) in order to learn from previous discutions on the client/server subject.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps lean towards JAX-RS unless you want to deal with low level or have any constraints on protocol to use. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html.